# How can I recreate this washed out / tie dyed effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

How could I recreate this gradient washed out effect in PS?

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried anything, and if so, where did it go wrong? Anything else you can show will be of great help.

Comment: I am interested to learn this tie and dye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try recreating the color effect using [**tie dye brushes**](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/21814379415604858/), and then the `Smudge` tool to create the transition to white. For example:

[image]